# Optimal number of socket send(..) threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets

If I have array of N sockets and I need to send(..) data to each of the sockets, with the highest possible speed, what will be the optimum number of threads to do it? OS is linux.

E.g. if I have C physical cores, should it be C threads each of them executing send(..)? Will it be efficient? In other words, my question how send(..) syscall is processed by linux kernel and how data supplied to it will scheduled in the kernel. I remember reading from BSD sockets documentation, that actually all send(..) syscalls for sockets are putting data in the queue that is processed by one thread, so the code:

```
thread1 -> send(sock1, ..)
..
threadN -> send(sockN, ..)
```

will be more or less equivalent (minus time by processing data by send before sending to kernel) by network performance to the code

```
thread -> send(sock1, ..), ..., send(sockN, ..)
```

But that was from the book dated middle-1990, I think modern OSes should change after that times.

Comment: My personal experience, do try to make the system as efficient as possible. 
Just try to make it slightly more efficient then required. This tactic has the best result to effort ratio.

Why do you need the system to be super efficient?

Comment: I'm reviewing the code of the software that at certain (rare) period of time needs to send a lot of messages to a lot of sockets. E.g. once in an hour, it sends 100 different messages to 100 sockets (1 message to each socket), as fast as possible. Currently they have solution with 100 threads and I don't think this is efficient (they have 10/20 physical/virtual cores). Have an argue with developers, trying to understand the correct approach.

Comment: Well I have done this in 1 single thread for 150 devices. Each getting a message payload the size of 128 bytes.

So ya multithreading is not efficient in this case.

Putting the whole thing in a for loop was quite enough.
Also I made the loop sleep for 10 micro seconds at the end of 1 full round of sending messages. That reduced the cpu usage from 82% to 12%.

Comment: If you are sending 100 messages to 100 threads there is no question to answer. You need as many threads as there are sockets, and fiddling around with that can only make it slower. `send()` to any specific socket is already sequentialized within the kernel, and the network by its nature already sequentializes outbound data to all destinations. Let the operating system do its work. Don't try to help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your threads are supposed to do exactly the same thing I would say the best thing to do is do that thing inside a single thread with an iterator.

What you can do is define a linked list to hold nodes which would hold the file descriptors for each socket. At the end of every hour iterate through the list and send the packages.
You can define the data sending function inside the class so that your work reduces in the main function.

I believe it is better than maintaining 100s of threads which are sleeping.

Also ensure to use the sleep function instead of any kind of milli second check. This will definitely reduce the CPU usage of the code while keeping the performance the same.